# Apply join, sort on date column and select the first row where one of the column value is not null

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables(Table A and Table B) in a Postgres DB.

Both have "id" column in common. Table A has one column called "id" and Table B has three columns: "id, date, value($)".
For each "id" of Table A there exists multiple rows in Table B in the following format - (id, date, value).

For instance, for Table A with "id" as 1 if there exists following rows in Table B:

- (1, 2018-06-21, null)
- (1, 2018-06-20, null)
- (1, 2018-06-19, 202)
- (1, 2018-06-18, 200)

I would like to extract the most recent dated non-null value. For example for id - 1, the result should be 202. Please share your thoughts or let me know in case more info is required.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the solution I went ahead with:***

```
with mapping as ( select distinct table1.id, table2.value, table2.date, row_number() over (partition by table1.id order by table2.date desc nulls last) as row_number
        from table1
        left join table2 on table2.id=table1.id and table2.value is not null
)
select * from mapping where row_number = 1
```

Let me know if there is scope for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You may very well want an inner join, not an outer join. If you have an id in table1 that does not exist in table2 or that has only null values you will get NULL for both date and value. This is due to the how outer join works. What it says is if nothing in the right side table matches the ON condition then return NULL for each column in that table. So

```
with mapping as 
     (select distinct table1.id
           , table2.value
           , table2.date
           , row_number() over (partition by table1.id order by table2.date desc nulls last) as row_number
        from table1
        join table2 on table2.id=table1.id and table2.value is not null
     )
select * 
  from mapping 
 where row_number = 1;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ac82fe67a41617720315f2fcbc530950) of each here. Your query worked because all your test data satisfied the 1st condition of the ON condition. You really need test data that fails to see what your query does.  
***Caution:*** DATE and VALUE are very poor choice for a column names. Both are [SQL standard reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), although not Postgres specifically. Further DATE is a Postgres data type. Having columns with names the same as datatype leads to confusion.